# Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'program' could not be found

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to connect my dev certificate to my iOS SDK. I did all what was in the guide, but after compiling and running I got the error:

```
Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's
Identifier 'myProgram' could not be found
```

Comment: are you a member of the apple developer programm ?

Comment: Have you created and downloaded a provisioning profile from the member centre and added it to Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In few words, here is what you need :

- generate a certificate to a certificate authority (keychain access program)
- log on apple developer program
- create an app ID
- create a **Development** provisionning profile with this app ID
- download this provisionning profile and double-click on it to have it installed on XCode
- the bundle identifier of your application should be the same than the app ID you created

Have you done all those steps?

Comment: Yes I've done it and already repair it, but now i having another problem: i create distribution profile with costumer device name and id, add and compiled it in ios sdk. I've all done according apple ad hoc guide, but my costumer cann't run project on device what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Even if after one year... try this:

http://code-dojo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html

it's a pretty common problem working with Jenkins. Hope it will be useful (maybe you're still banging your head against a wall ;))