# Error to build app with xcode

Tags: xcode, build

i always got error:

> Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the
>   application's Identifier '...' could not be found

what's this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in IOS SDK got message: Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'program' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522616/in-ios-sdk-got-message-code-sign-error-a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurred because your applications bundle identifier is not same as the Application Identifier in your provisioning profile. 
 To fix this replace the Bundle Identifier property in your applications Info.plist file with the Application Identifier in your provisioning profile.